# Using table of Integrals an

Tags: calculus, integration

So I am trying to integrate this integral $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2+4z+29}}\,dz$$

I know I cannot factor so I complete the square to get:

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2+4z+29}}\,dz=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(z+2)^2+25}}\,dz$$

Then I use U-sub. and let $$u=z+2$$ and $$du=dz$$

So then I got $$\int \frac{1}{u^2+5^2}\,du$$

Using $$\int \frac{1}{x^2+a^2}=\frac{1}{a}\arctan\Bigl(\frac{x}{a}\Bigr)+c$$ I get: $$\frac{1}{5}\arctan\Bigl(\frac{u}{5}\Bigr)+c=\frac{1}{5}\arctan\Bigl(\frac{z+2}{5}\Bigr)+c$$

However, my homework assignment website is saying that I have an incorrect answer and I have logically went through each step and can not see my mistake! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The square root has vanished midway through your calculation... try substituting $x+2=5\tan(\theta)$.

Comment: I just realized that the original problem as a square root! Because of the square root, I should use: $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}=ln|x+\sqrt{x^2\pm a^2}|+c$$$

Answer (score 2):

The square root should not have vanished when you did the $u$ substitution. To combine a couple of steps into one, use the substitution $x+2 = 5\sinh t \implies dx = 5\cosh t dt$

$$\int \frac{5\cosh t}{\sqrt{25\sinh^2 t + 25}}dt = \int \frac{5\cosh t}{5\cosh t}dt = t+C$$

Then undo the substitution to get the answer

$$\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{x+2}{5}\right)+C$$